# setting xml StackOverflowException error

Tags: c#, stack-overflow, setting

When I try to read my settings I get an error. I know I write wrong somewhere. the procedure to be done alone as I couldn't find much information.

//Settings read code

```
  public static class proSave
    {
        public static propertyClass oku
        {
            get
            {
                XmlSerializer serialize = new XmlSerializer(typeof(propertyClass));
                var stream = new StreamReader("settings.xml");
                return (propertyClass)serialize.Deserialize(stream);

            }
        }
    }
```

setting apply code

```
   namespace property
      {
        [Serializable]
        public class propertyClass
        {
            private string _serverName = proSave.oku.serverName;
            [Description("Server Bağlantı Adı"), Category("Server Setting")]
            public string serverName { get { return _serverName; }}

            private string _databaseName = proSave.oku.serverName;
            [Description("Server Bağlantısı Dosya Adı"), Category("Server Setting")]
            public string databaseName { get { return _serverName; } }

            private string _user = proSave.oku.user;
            [Description("Server Bağlantısı kullanıcı adı"), Category("Server Setting")]
            public string user { get { return _user; } }

            private string _password = proSave.oku.password;
            [Description("Server Bağlantısı kullanıcı şifresi"), Category("Server Setting")]
            public string password { get { return _password; } }

            private int _gridHeight = proSave.oku.gridHeight;
            [Description("Grid Hücre Yükseklik Ayarı \nFormlar Yenilendiğinde etkinleştirilecektir."), Category("Grid Ayarları")]
            public int gridHeight { get { return _gridHeight; } }  


        }
    }
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<propertyClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <serverName>1</serverName>
  <databaseName>Kadir</databaseName>
  <user>as</user>
  <gridHeight>40</gridHeight>
</propertyClass>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Could you provide some detail on the error and the content of your settings.xml file please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a circular reference in your propertyClass which is causing a loop which eventually results in a StackOverflow exception (referencing proSave.oku, which is an instance of the propertyClass, within the propertyClass). Removing this reference in your propertyClass fixes your issue - the rest of your code can be left as it is:

```
[Serializable]
public class propertyClass
{
    [Description("Server Bağlantı Adı"), Category("Server Setting")]
    public string serverName { get; set; }

    [Description("Server Bağlantısı Dosya Adı"), Category("Server Setting")]
    public string databaseName { get; set; }

    [Description("Server Bağlantısı kullanıcı adı"), Category("Server Setting")]
    public string user { get; set; }

    [Description("Server Bağlantısı kullanıcı şifresi"), Category("Server Setting")]
    public string password { get; set; }

    [Description("Grid Hücre Yükseklik Ayarı \nFormlar Yenilendiğinde etkinleştirilecektir."), Category("Grid Ayarları")]
    public int gridHeight { get; set; }
}
```

If you wanted to extend the implementation to prevent reading the xml file each time, you could further modify your proSave class to "cache" the settings, for example:

```
public static class proSave
{
    private static propertyClass settings;

    private const string SettingsFilePath = "C:\\settings.xml";

    public static propertyClass oku
    {
        get
        {
            if (settings == null)
            {
                settings = GetSettings();
                return settings;
            }

            return settings;
        }
    }

    public static void SaveSettings(propertyClass settings)
    {
        XmlSerializer writer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(propertyClass));

        using (FileStream file = File.Create(SettingsFilePath))
        {
            writer.Serialize(file, settings);
        }
    }

    private static propertyClass GetSettings()
    {
        XmlSerializer serialize = new XmlSerializer(typeof(propertyClass));

        using (var stream = new StreamReader(SettingsFilePath))
        {
            return (propertyClass)serialize.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

You would need to handle IOExceptions if the file was locked when writing the settings back in the SaveSettings() method.

You could also look into alternatives, such as using the built-in ConfigurationManager or implementing a custom [ConfigurationSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx). Hope this helps.

Comment: How do I follow a path other for much of read and write operations ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question - could you provide a bit more detail, thanks.

Comment: there is a method of writing and reading operations of the Automatically settings I can do? the aim here is constantly opening and closing the file, comforting in a way to benefit. I am writing with Google translation.

Comment: I've just made a edit to my original answer which gives an example of how you could avoid reading the xml file each time, which is what I think you were getting at in your last comment! Hope this helps?

Comment: Thank you. There is no problem with the reading part .
Finally, how can I save all the action.

Comment: Again, I'm not sure what you mean, sorry. Do you want  to be able to write back changes made to the propertyClass back to the settings.xml file? You wouldn't normally do this as settings like this are normally pretty static. Apologies, but I'm guessing the meaning of your question!

Comment: Yes, I want to save the settings.

Comment: You can call Serialize() on the XmlSerializer (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms172873.aspx) to write the object back to xml if you wish. Just be mindful of contention on the file - it may be locked for example. If there are lots of users and these settings change frequently, storing them in a database may be a better way to go.

Comment: I amended the answer again to include saving the settings back! As mentioned before, you would need to handle any IOExceptions in cases where the file is locked. Hope this gives you everything you need?

Comment: Thank you. the authors try and answer as soon as possible.

Comment: '   private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            proSave.SaveSettings(proSave.oku);
        }'  problem solved.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am grateful for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<propertyClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <serverName>1</serverName>
  <databaseName>Kadir</databaseName>
  <user>as</user>
  <gridHeight>40</gridHeight>
</propertyClass>
```

System.StackOverflowException ' type of exception to be thrown .

Comment: Use the [edit] link below your question to add additional information. Do not write it into the Answer box - that is only for contributions that answer the Question you asked. Stack Overflow is not a typical "forum" - any (minimal) discussion should be carried on in Comments.